# How do I deal with an edge case when replacing None values in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, nonetype

I am looking to replace the None value in a list with the preceding value but taking into account edge cases where the first value is a None or the preceding value is a None; if the first value is None it should remain None. So for example below are the inputs and outputs one would expect:

```
[1,2,None,3,None] --> [1,2,2,3,3]
[None,1,2,2,None,None,3] --> [None,1,2,2,2,2,3]
```

I attempted something with a loop but I am unsure how to take care of the edge case:

```
myList = [1,None,1,2,None]
def replaceNone(myList):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[i] is not None:
            res.append(myList[i])
        else:
            res.append(myList[i-1])
    return res

replaceNone(myList)
```

Comment: What is the expected output on a list like: `[None, None, 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
new_list = [listA[index - 1] if i == None and index>= 1 else i for index, i in enumerate(listA)]
```

For example:

```
listA = [1,2,None,3,None]
listB = [None, 2, 3, None, 4]


new_list = [listA[index - 1] if i == None and index>= 1 else i for index, i in enumerate(listA)] 
new_list2 = [listB[index - 1] if i == None and index>= 1 else i for index, i in enumerate(listB)] 

print(new_list)
print(new_list2)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3] #listA
[None, 2, 3, 3, 4] #listB
```

Which seems to be the desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use minimalistic code with faster performance, I came up with below solution that uses the Pandas library, which might be useful in this case:

```
import pandas as pd

def replaceNone(myList):
    myList = pd.DataFrame(myList)
    return myList.fillna(method='ffill').values.flatten().tolist()

myList = [None,1,2,2,None,None,3]
replaceNone(myList)
```